# Tiny C++ YAML reader/writer

Tags: c++, serialization, yaml, formats

I'm writing an embedded C++ program, and need to add serialization/deserialization. The format should be human readable and writeable, and I would much prefer to use (a subset of) a standard format like YAML. I also prefer YAML to JSON since it is more concise.

While yaml-cpp has the exact functionality I'd like, the source code is almost 300K and would almost double my code size, which seems excessive to me just in order to add human readable serialization/deserialization.

Before I start writing my own reader/writer for a subset of YAML, I'd like to first check whether this already exists? I have not been able to find one, but would much prefer to use existing code rather than rolling my own. Are there any C or C++ YAML readers/writers out there of, say, 50K code or less? I only need functionality for the basic data structures (scalar, array, hash), not any advanced stuff.

With many thanks in advance.

Comment: JSON is a subset of YAML, meaning it has less code. IF you care about code size then use JSON.

Comment: BTW, there's always INI file format, which is pretty lean and gets some jobs done just as well as other formats.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I care about code size, but would prefer the less strict and less verbose format of YAML to JSON, since non-specialists will be writing input in the format. The reason for using a standard format is to be able to easily import program output in python and other scripting languages for postprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

The Oops library is doing what you are looking for. It is written for serialization using reflection and supports YAML format as well.

https://bitbucket.org/barczpe/oops

Comment: Thanks! Functionally, it looks great. But Oops is 648kib of code! That's even bigger than libyaml's 300k code. My search was for a *small* yaml reader/writer for embedded applications (which should be possible to make due to how simple the format is).

Comment: The Oops library is much more than a yaml reader/writer. It supports 2 other file formats as well and all logic you need to store the information in C++ datastructure.
The yaml parser and formatter are few files only. You can take it from the library, if you wish. rOopsYamlParser.h / .cpp and rOopsYamlFormat.h / .cpp are the main files, but there are some dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds excellent. I'll try to extract just the yaml part and see if I can get that to work. I'll report back when I've had a chance to do so.